# sort an array by relationship in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting, object

I want to sort an array.

The items in the array have relationships.

eg. `list[5]` should be `before list[9]` but `after list[3]`

---

The expected value in the sample is just for testing. It does not really exist.

---

Here's a sample array with the relationships and an expected index.

```
var list = [{
  id: '0001',
  before: '0002',
  expected: 0
}, {
  id: '0002',
  before: '0007',
  after: '0001',
  expected: 4
}, {
  id: '0003',
  before: '0006',
  after: '0001',
  expected: 2
}, {
  id: '0004',
  after: '0007',
  expected: 11
}, {
  id: '0005',
  before: '0003',
  after: '0001',
  expected: 1
}, {
  id: '0006',
  before: '0002',
  after: '0001',
  expected: 3
}, {
  id: '0007',
  before: '00010',
  after: '0002',
  expected: 5
}, {
  id: '0008',
  before: '00012',
  after: '0007',
  expected: 9
}, {
  id: '0009',
  before: '0011',
  after: '0001',
  expected: 7
}, {
  id: '0010',
  before: '0009',
  after: '0007',
  expected: 6
}, {
  id: '0011',
  before: '0008',
  after: '0001',
  expected: 8
}, {
  id: '0012',
  before: '0004',
  after: '0010',
  expected: 10
}];
```

Comment: If you happen to find the solution in time, please answer it yourself here. I'm quite curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on Jan Turoň: here is an example of how your problem (finding a total order in a directed acyclic graph) is unsolvable:

```
var list = [{ id:A, before:B }, // "First" in total order
            { id:B, after:A }, // "Last" in total order
            { id:C, after:A, before:B },
            { id:D, after:A, before:B }];
```

There is no total ordering between `C` and `D`: you could call them equal, but what if instead of `D` you have a list `D0 -> D1 -> D2`?

Depending on your type of problem this can be solved by preprocessing: reducing a path of nodes of degree 2 to a single node and calling parallel paths through nodes of degree 2 identical (also to be reduced to a single node). At the end of such a preprocessing you're left with a tree - which in your case should be a list / path (or a single node, since you reduce paths of vertices of degree 2).

Note that the information "before" and "after" are redundant: you only really require one of them. The statement "A is before B" is equivalent to "B is after A" and your acyclic graph only needs to reflect either the direction "before" or "after". What you're then looking for is a path through the graph containing all nodes (since they are directed "before" or "after" you automatically get a path from first to last in order - if such a path exists):

```
// First build the adjacency list for "X before Y"
var befores = { };
for(var i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    befores[list[i].id] = null;
function insert(before, after) {
    if(!before || !after)
        return;
    befores[before] = { next:befores[before], id:after };
}
for(var i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    var item = list[i];
    insert(item.after, item.id); // "X after Y" -> "Y before X"
    insert(item.id, item.before);
}

// build complete the graph as a lookup table
// id is "before" all elements in lookup[id]
var lookup = { };
for(var i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    var id = list[i].id;
    var beforeList = [id];
    var beforeSet = { };
    beforeSet[id] = 1;
    // use "A before B" and "B before C" to gain "A before C"
    for(var j = 0; j < beforeList.length; ++j) {
        for(var item = befores[beforeList[j]]; item != null; item = item.next) {
            if(!beforeSet[item.id]) {
                beforeList.push(item.id);
                beforeSet[item.id] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    // for our comparison we don't care if id is in beforeSet
    lookup[id] = beforeSet;
    // slice beforeList to get only the elements after id here:
    //beforeList = beforeList.slice(1, beforeList.length);
}

// Now sort using the following
// a) if rhs is present in "before"-set of lhs then lhs < rhs
// b) if rhs is not present then rhs < lhs
// c) there is information missing from our graph if a) and b) for lhs analogous lead to a different conclusion!
list.sort(function(lhs, rhs) {
    if(!lhs.after || !rhs.before) return -1;
    if(!lhs.before || !rhs.after) return 1;
    if(lhs.id === rhs.id) return 0;
    // different ids guaranteed, doesn't matter if lookup[id] contains id itself
    var result = lookup[lhs.id][rhs.id] ? -1 : 1;
    // expect reversing lhs and rhs to get inverse result
    var expected = lookup[rhs.id][lhs.id] ? 1 : -1;
    if(result != expected) {
        // alert: there is no adjacency information between lhs and rhs!
    }
    return result;
});
```

Test it out yourself:

```js
var list = [{
  id: '0001',  before: '0002',  expected: 0}, {
  id: '0002',  before: '0007',  after: '0001',  expected: 4}, {
  id: '0003',  before: '0006',  after: '0001',  expected: 2}, {
  id: '0004',  after: '0007',  expected: 11}, {
  id: '0005',  before: '0003',  after: '0001',  expected: 1}, {
  id: '0006',  before: '0002',  after: '0001',  expected: 3}, {
  id: '0007',  before: '0010',  after: '0002',  expected: 5}, {
  id: '0008',  before: '0012',  after: '0007',  expected: 9}, {
  id: '0009',  before: '0011',  after: '0001',  expected: 7}, {
  id: '0010',  before: '0009',  after: '0007',  expected: 6}, {
  id: '0011',  before: '0008',  after: '0001',  expected: 8}, {
  id: '0012',  before: '0004',  after: '0010',  expected: 10
}];

// re-used variable
var count = list.length;
var out = document.getElementById("out");

function toHTMLItem(item) {
  var result = item.expected + " (";
  if(item.after) result += item.after + " &lt; ";
  result += "<b>" + item.id + "</b>";
  if(item.before) result += " &lt; " + item.before;
  result += ")";
  return result;
}

function toHTMLList(list) {
  var result = "<p>";
  for(var i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    result += toHTMLItem(list[i]) + "<br>";
  }
  result += "</p>";
  return result;
}

// out.innerHTML += toHTMLList(list);

var befores = { };
for(var i = 0; i < count; ++i)
 befores[list[i].id] = null;
function insert(before, after) {
 if(!before || !after)
  return;
 befores[before] = { next:befores[before], id:after };
}
for(var i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
 var item = list[i];
 insert(item.after, item.id);
 insert(item.id, item.before);
}

function toHTMLTable(table, list) {
  var result = "<p>";
  var count = list.length;
  for(var i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    var id = list[i].id;
    result += id + " < ";
    for(var item = table[id]; item != null; item = item.next) {
      result += item.id + ", ";
    }
    result += "o<br>";
  }
  result += "</p>";
  return result;
}

// out.innerHTML += toHTMLTable(befores, list);

// next build a lookup-table of a completed adjacency list
var lookup = { };
for(var i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
 var id = list[i].id;
 var beforeList = [id];
 var beforeSet = { };
 beforeSet[id] = 1;
 // use "A before B" and "B before C" to gain "A before C"
 for(var j = 0; j < beforeList.length; ++j) {
  for(var item = befores[beforeList[j]]; item != null; item = item.next) {
   if(!beforeSet[item.id]) {
    beforeList.push(item.id);
    beforeSet[item.id] = 1;
   }
  }
 }
 beforeList = beforeList.slice(1, beforeList.length);
 beforeList.sort();
 lookup[id] = beforeSet;
}

function toHTMLLookup(lookup, list) {
  var result = "<p>";
  for(var i = 0, imax = list.length; i < imax; ++i) {
    var id = list[i].id;
    var bs = lookup[id];
    result += id + " < ";
    for(var j = 0, jmax = imax; j < jmax; ++j) {
      if(j == i) continue;
      if(bs[list[j].id]) result += list[j].id + ", ";
    }
    result += "o<br>";
  }
  result += "</p>";
  return result;
}

// out.innerHTML += toHTMLLookup(lookup, list);

// Search function in befores:
// a) if rhs is present in union of befores set lhs < rhs
// b) if rhs is not present in union of befores set rhs < lhs
list.sort((function() {
  var enableAlert = true;
  return function(lhs, rhs) {
    if(!lhs.after || !rhs.before) return -1;
    if(!lhs.before || !rhs.after) return 1;
    if(lhs.id === rhs.id) return 0;
    // different ids guaranteed, doesn't matter if lookup[id] contains id itself
    var result = lookup[lhs.id][rhs.id] ? -1 : 1;
    // expect reversing lhs and rhs to get inverse result
    var expected = lookup[rhs.id][lhs.id] ? 1 : -1;
    if(enableAlert && result != expected) {
      // restrict to a single alert per execution
      enableAlert = false;
      out.innerHTML += "<p><b>ALERT</b> unresolved adjacency between " + lhs.id + " and " + rhs.id + "!</p>";
    }
    return result;
  };
})());

// out.innerHTML += toHTMLList(list);

var error = count;
for(var i = 0; i < error; ++i) {
 if(list[i].expected != i)
  error = i;
}
if(error < count) {
  out.innerHTML += "<h2>error!</h2><p>list[" + error + "] contains " + toHTMLItem(list[i]) + "</p>";
} else {
  out.innerHTML += "<h2>success!</h2>";
}
// Finally print the output
out.innerHTML += toHTMLList(list);
```

```html
<div id="out"/>
```

For the general topic of this question consider [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).

Comment: I am not sure about the redundancy: "after" doesn't need to be *direct* predecessor. Maybe I'm wrong and I just can't visualize it. Could you please demonstrate how would you exactly build the tree from the OP list? Could you figure out an algorithm that satisfies one (or all) possible solutions satisfying "before" and "after" rules?

Comment: @JanTuroň same for "before". if `A` is before `B` and `C` is after `A`, you have two pieces of information: `A` -> `B` and `A` -> `C` if your arrows stand for "before", `B` -> `A` and `C` -> `A` if your arrows stand for "after". The relationship between `B` and `C` is not defined here (your graph is a tree). You could get an additional piece of information `B` before `C` and complete your graph with `B` -> `C` (before), the arrow `A` -> `C` doesn't mean direct neighbour, it means "before".

Comment: @JanTuroň Note that the graph (`ABC`) for "before" looks the same with arrows reversed for "after" - because it's the same information. You could also color your arrows `black` and `white` for "before" and "after" respectively. When inspecting the graph you'll note that the rules for traversing `black` arrows are reversed for `whites`.

Comment: Right. Some information may be redundant. Or contradiction: cycle detection seems to be a good model how to find out if there is at least one solution. Maybe Prolog would be better language to solve it, but iterative solution is quite a challenge, I guess.

Comment: @JanTuroň what you're actually looking for is a path through the graph containing all nodes (since they are directed "before" or "after" you automatically get a path from first to last in order - if such a path exists)

Comment: I considered pre-order tree traversing. But it is not exactly tree, it's (hopefully) acyclic oriented graph. I guess the solution would be construction of such graph (I mean to find direct neighbors) and to find traversing algorithm. If you could describe it as iterative algorithm, I'd share a bounty. It is not necesarilly unsolvable, there actually IS a solution (the expected values).

Comment: @JanTuroň check out my implementation :)

Comment: That's enlightening, good job! I should refresh my graph theory a bit. Definitely worth a bounty as soon as it is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer, too long for a comment. You probably figured this out, I just hope it helps someone to find the solution.

1. The solution can be impossible or one of many
2. If there is oriented cycle in "before" or "after" traversing, there is no solution (@BeyelerStudios' credit)
3. The first one doesn't have "after", the last one doesn't have "before"
4. The second one has to have the first one id in "after", it can be set
5. The set can be sorted recursively
6. How to determine the position of the remaining elements I couldn't figure out.

This function can be useful in in-place sort: move an item in array:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype,"move",{
  value: function(from,to) {
    var x = this.splice(from,1);
    this.splice(to,0,x[0]);
  }
});

var list = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
// move the index 1 (b) to position 3 (after d)
list.move(1,3); // acdbe
```

Good luck.

Comment: on your second point: there is no loop in my example (the graph is directed) and if you change `{id:D, after:A, before:B}` from my example to `{id:D, after:C, before:B}` you'd get the solution `ACDB` while still having arrows `A`->`B` and `A`->`C`->`B`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this right, `expected` is the index you'd like the element to be?  In that case, you can use `.sort()` with a custom sorting function.

```
list.sort(function (a, b) {
  var ae = a.expected,
      be = b.expected;

  if (ae > be) return 1;
  if (ae < be) return -1;
  if (ae === be) return 0;
});
```

(You can make that block shorter if you'd like at the sacrifice of readability.)

Comment: the compare does not exist ;) it is just to test it later

Comment: I just updated the question to better describe the problem

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a custom sorting function, as mentioned by Mike. I think what you really want is this:

```
list.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (/* a before b, b after a */) {
    return -1;
  } else if (/* b before a, a after b */) {
    return 1;
  } 
  return 0;
});
```

Basically, what you return in a custom sort function determines the relationship that the two arguments have with one another. Returning -1 means that the first item is before, +1 means that the second is before, and 0 means that there is no relationship available.

For your "a after b, b before a" criteria, perhaps try `a.id === b.before|| b.id === a.after`, with the reverse for b after a.

This may or may not return as expected depending on your exact list - if you have a lot of missing or conflicting data, the sort might end up not returning exactly as you expect.

In general, I would avoid having both "before" and "after" information - you should only need one or the other, and having both can introduce even more conflicts than just having a single relation.